# Rooting my Galaxy s4

Tags: rooting

I just can't.  I just switched from an iPhone to a galaxy s4 and i don't even know whwhere to start. It's version 4.4.4 model sgh m919 and it's so complicated I dont even know where to begin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device. Please use the search first before asking questions that have already been answered.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. If you look at the [How do I root my android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) you will notice that the SGH-M919 is not in that list. We allow a "how to root" question per device. A search for SGH-M919 did not return anything that told me how to root that device. Once a device is answered, that question is updated to contain the question. I also suggest you look though the [rootint tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info).

Comment: Furthermore, if you take a look at our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), you will notice we don't close any rooting question as duplicate to *that one* (at least not anymore since 01/2012). One rooting question per device is permitted, and then will be linked from that index. A second question still might be valid in case the described method is "expired" (e.g. only valid for a previous version of Android).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with the SGH-M919 NK2 (4.4.4) build as well.  Unfortunately, none of the one-click Root programs work as of right now, such as Kingo or iRoot.  BUT!!  Good news is that the NH7 Odin root package works to root the device.  So, to  go to this link, and download the root file.

http://download.chainfire.eu/328/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-jfltetmo-jfltetmo-sghm919.zip

Next, download Odin3, and follow these simple instructions from XDA:

http://www.jayceooi.com/how-to-install-galaxy-s4-firmware-i9500-i9505-with-odin/

Now, manually download SuperSU, or SuperUser from the Play store.
Voila!  You are now rooted on the NK2 build!

REMEMBER...you will be using the CF-Auto-Root[.tar.md5] in the PA box.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. But, really, as it stands, this is only a partial answer. The actual steps are linked to an external site. Which you state "instructions from XDA", but the link is not XDA. You should see the help center: [How to reference material written by others](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).